# SQL query where SUM contains where clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, where-clause

I have a database structure that looks like this:

```
|  Date  | Amount | Source |
|02/02/02| 100    |  "A"   |
|02/02/02| 300    |  "B"   |
|05/05/02| 200    |  "A"   |
|05/05/02| 700    |  "B"   |
|07/05/02| 200    |  "C"   |
|07/05/02| 700    |  "C"   |
```

What I'd like to do is get an SQL query that gives me output that looks like this:

```
|  Date  | Amount | Source |
|02/02/02| 100    |  "A"   |
|02/02/02| 300    |  "B"   |
|05/05/02| 200    |  "A"   |
|05/05/02| 700    |  "B"   |
|07/05/02| 900    |  "C"   |
```

Which is essentially group by date and source and then sum the amount. How do I do this?

Comment: The SQL is declarative language. Now, try to write in SQL language what you have declared in your post's last sentence in English.

Answer (score 2):

[here](http://sql.sh/fonctions/agregation/sum) you can see that you basically need :

```
SELECT Date, SUM(Amount) AS Total_Amount, Source FROM my_table GROUP BY Date, Source
```

Comment: Add "source" to the "GROUP BY" clause.